# React axios .then() doesn't run

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

```
useEffect( () => {
const fetchdata =  async () => {
  
  return ( await axios.get(serverPath).then(res=>{
   addNewSubtitle(res.data)
  }))
  
};
 const result = fetchdata(); //addnewSubtitle(result.data)}, [serverPath])
```

The .then doesn't run and I have also tried the result.data commented below which returns undefined.
I have checked the syntax again and again and it seems correct. I don't know what could cause the then function to not run

Comment: try removing the `await`

Comment: How are you using `result.data` and how do you know it's not running?

Comment: i have tried removing await and async, still doesnt work.

Comment: I know it doesn't bcz the addNewSubtitle function is supposed to add a new subtitle which it doesn't, meaning the then function not running. But when i call it out of then beneath fetchdata() it runs but result.data doesn't contain the text being sent from express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 function request() {
  const fetchdata = async () => await axios.get( serverPath )
  const result =  fetchdata()
  result.then(res=>addNewSubtitle(res.data))
}
request()
```

}, [serverPath])

The result was a promise object and when .then was called outside the fetchdata function it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to return what’s in your .then() to use it—

```
return ( await axios.get(serverPath).then(res=>{
        return addNewSubtitle(res.data)
      }))
```

Comment: you don't have to use `.then()` when you are using async await.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function request() {
      const fetchdata = async () => await axios.get(serverPath).then(res => res.data)
      const result = await fetchdata()
    }
    request()
  }, [serverPath])
```

Comment: Can you get the data by console.log the variable result? @BassamIshaq

Comment: result.data comes out to be empty

Comment: Is `result` empty?

Comment: result was a promise object. I posted the solution as my answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData(){
        await axios.get(serverPath).then(res=>addNewSubtitle(res.data))
    }
    fetchData()
}, [serverPath])
```

i don't know what you're doing but this is my basic format on axios call within the useEffect hook